# Displaying Multiple Rectangles Using A 2D Array c# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, arrays

So in simple I have a 2d array storing the x and y values for each square I want to display

array = ((10,10),(25,50),(5,40))

I have used this for loop to output the square, but it only shows the last quadrantes of the array, from the example only being one square at (5,40).

```
int locationX = 150;
int locationY = 150;
        private void player_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // player
            pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
            Rectangle player = new Rectangle(locationX, locationY, 10, 10);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, player);
        }
```

The code above is the first instance of the rectangle, then when trying to output multiple squares,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
     locationX = array[i][0];
     locationY = array[i][1];
     panPlayer.Invalidate();
}
```

Is this something to do with objects? If it is then how would I go about creating objects in a way were I can continue to add to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess it could probably be because your are bad implementing the array, I manage to draw several rectangles at the same time using the method DrawRectangles from Graphics class and making an array of type Retangle.

Here's the code:

```
private Graphics Grafs;

    public PaintForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Grafs = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
        Rectangle[] rects = new Rectangle[3];

        rects[0] = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 20, 20);
        rects[1] = new Rectangle(e.X + 50, e.Y + 50, 20, 20);
        rects[2] = new Rectangle(e.X + 100, e.Y + 100, 20, 20);
        
        Grafs.DrawRectangles(pen, rects);
    }
```

Hope this help.